# Render form field random times

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a question regarding field rendering in forms. I have this code:

```
class RTForm(forms.ModelForm):

    type_options = {
        'error': {
            'label': _('Error'),
        },
        'warning': {
            'label': _('Warning'),
        },
        'off': {
            'label': _('Disable'),
        }
    }

    choice_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(k, v['label']) for k, v in type_options.items()],
        required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(
            attrs={
                class="choices"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = RT

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rt = kwargs.pop('instance', None)

        errors = create_error_list(rt.type)
        warnings = create_warning_list(rt.type)

        super(RTV, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and what I wanna do is have on my template as many choice_type fields as the number of errors/warnings returned in the lists inside the init(different number each time). Is that possible? I can't figure out a possible solution.

Comment: Have you considered using [django message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask would be possible with the help of a dynamic class that you create yourself with `type` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

I am not sure that I understand the business requirements of your problem correctly, however I would do something like this in a view to create a custom form:

```
choice_type = forms.ChoiceField( # this is your class
   choices=[(k, v['label']) for k, v in type_options.items()],
   required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
           class="choices"
       })
)

# let's say that I want my custom form to have two choice fields:
formfields = {}
formfields['choice_field1']= choice_type 
formfields['choice_field2']= choice_type 

# Now I can create my custom class
form_class = type('CustomForm', (django.forms.Form,), formfields )

# Finally I will create an instance of my custom class
form = form_class()

# Ok ! form can be used in my view as any normal django form !!
```